# XSLT dynamic sort using variables

Tags: sorting, xslt

I am trying to do dynamic sort based on values passed from the dropdown list. I am setting them as variables and using them in sort.

I am using XSLT version 1.0.

Below is the code:

test.php file -

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('testxslt');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement( "<?xml version='1.0' ?>\n".           
         "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='xml_stylesort.xsl' ?>\n". 
               "<items></items>");             

$_POST['sort_by']='price_desc';

//for sorting
if(isset($_POST['sort_by']) && !empty($_POST['sort_by'])){
          $arr = explode('_', $_POST['sort_by']);

          if($arr[1] == "asc")      $sortorder = 'ascending';
          if($arr[1] == "desc")      $sortorder = 'descending';

          // xml_appendNode($objXmlDom, $objDocNode, "sortby",$arr[0]);
           $xml->addChild( "sortby",$arr[0]);

              $xml->addChild( "sortorder",$sortorder);

         // xml_appendTextNode($objXmlDom, $objDocNode, "sortorder", $sortorder);

          if($arr[0] == "price")      $type = 'number';
          else                                  $type = 'text';

          $xml->addChild( "sorttype", $type);
        //  xml_appendTextNode($objXmlDom, $objDocNode, "sorttype", $type);

}


$sql = mysql_query("select * from items") or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_object($sql))
{
    $item = $xml->addChild('item');
    $item->addAttribute('id', $row->id);
    $item->addChild('name', $row->name);
    $item->addChild('qty', $row->qty);
    $item->addChild('price', $row->price);
}


Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());

?>
```

xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">



    <xsl:variable name="sortby">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="sortby != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="items/sortby" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'price'" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>


          <xsl:variable name="sorttype">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="sorttype != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="items/sorttype" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'text'" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>


         <xsl:variable name="sortorder">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="sortorder != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="items/sortorder" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'ascending'" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>Item List</h2>


          <div style="margin:20px;">
          <label>Sort by:      | <xsl:value-of select="items/sortby" /> | <xsl:value-of select="items/sorttype" /> | <xsl:value-of select="items/sortorder" />  </label>
                     <form id="sortform" method="post">
                        <select name="sort_by"  onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('sortform').submit();">
                            <option> Select </option>
                                 <option  value="price_asc">Price ASC</option>
                                     <option value="price_desc">Price DESC</option>
                                 <option  value="name_asc">Name ASC</option>
                                 <option  value="name_desc">Name DESC</option>
                        </select>
                     </form>
          </div>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item">

                                               <xsl:sort data-type="{$sorttype}" select="*[name()=$sortby]"  order="{$sortorder}"  /> 

                <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="qty"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="qty * price"/></td>
                </tr>
             </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post an example of the input + indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Your code doesn't even show what $sortby is.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please check it if I made it clear enough now.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have edited the question and added test code to it so that problem can be reproduced. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is with the setting of your three variables at the start of your XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="sortby">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="sortby != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="items/sortby" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'price'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

The condition for the `xsl:when` is not correct. It is looking for a `sortby` element under the document node, which doesn't exist, as the root element is actually `items`.

It should be the following:

```
 <xsl:when test="items/sortby != ''">
```

Similarly for the other two variables.

As an aside, it looks like you are writing XML with an `xsl:stylesheet` processing instruction to do the transformation on the client. If you are PHP you should perhaps doing the transformation of the XML on the server, then just writing out the HTML result. That way you could get PHP to pass in the sort values as parameters, rather than appending them to the XML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created this as an example for testing, and we are getting values in variables fine. I think there is a problem in sort statement.

Comment: With the XSLT you have currently shown, the sort is working, but it will always sort the `item` elements in `price` order. It is not picking up the values from the XML. If your XSLT is actually different to what is shown in the question, you really need to edit the question to show a truly representative example to allow others to reproduce the error. Thank you!

Comment: That is right. It is sorting by price. what should I do solve it? I have replaced the text as mentioned by you earlier.

Comment: If you change all three variables as I describe in my answer, it should be fine. I've been testing it at http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpV if you want to look.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to reproduce the problem using your code. The one thing that I see is that you are trying to sort by:

```
select="@*[name()=$sortby]"
```

but your `product` nodes have no attributes. Perhaps you mean to sort by:

```
select="*[name()=$sortby]"
```

?

Comment: @michael.hor247K I have sorting parameters as: <sortby>price</sortby>  <sortorder>ascending</sortorder> <sorttype>number</sorttype> in XML.

Comment: @cartina I am afraid I can't help you without being able to reproduce your problem.